# Self-Signed Certificates With Java 8

Tags: java, security, applet, certificate, self-signed

I would really like to know if it is even possible to run a self-signed java applet in Java 8. I have tried everything possible except buying a certificate and I my self-signed applet gets blocked every time. I can only just make it accessible if I add an exception in Java Security Settings but Ive never had to do that for anything else and what user is actually going to go to that much trouble. Im using applets because I want to embed a DosBox on my site... But Im beginning to think that Java 8 just can't do self-signed applets, period.

Can anyone else manage to get their self signed applet through security? I'm about to lose my mind with this to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Self-signed certificates are not trusted, by definition. You have two choices:

1. Buy a code signing certificate.
2. Have the user adjust his Java Security Settings, or trust the publisher via the popup dialog.

This is how the system is designed and intended to work. It's been that way for 20 years.

Comment: I have to adjust the security settings AND click trust the publisher on the popup. Is there a way to make it trusted with just the popup dialog?

Comment: If this app. is only for your use, make it a (frame based) desktop app. If the app. is for others, get a code signing certificate.